# Run Consul Docker image in kubernetes as non root

Tags: docker, kubernetes, consul

I want to run consul in kubernetes but I am not allowed to run it as user root.

Therefore I added

```
RUN addgroup consul root
```

to the Dockerfile (derived `FROM consul:1.0.3`)

and start the deployment in kubernetes with

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    xyz.service: consul-deployment
  name: consul-deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 100
```

Now I expect kubernetes to start consul with user `100` (who used to be the user `consul` when I started it locally in Docker and now should be member in the group `root`).

But now I get the following the error when the pod is started

```
chown: /consul/data: Operation not permitted
```

The `chown` is executed in Consuls [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/hashicorp/docker-consul/blob/389ad67978f3fb9c43ae270e31c2d7b121df46c0/0.X/docker-entrypoint.sh) and I guess it (still) fails because user `100` is not root.

Can anybody explain me how to start a container with a non root user when the container has an entrypoint script expecting to be executed as root?

Comment: While not strictly speaking an answer to your question, you may enjoy some success by running their entrypoint in `-x` mode, to see what the two values actually are that is causing [this test](https://github.com/hashicorp/docker-consul/blob/389ad67978f3fb9c43ae270e31c2d7b121df46c0/0.X/docker-entrypoint.sh#L81) to fail; `command: ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "/bin/sh", "-x", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]` in your PodSpec should in theory do that. BTW, just being a member of the `root` group does absolutely nothing for one's ability to `chown` things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up in fixing Consuls `docker-entrypoint.sh` to check if the user is root before executing the chown command by adding some `if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]` tests.

[You can find the patch on GitHub.](https://github.com/DatzAtWork/docker-consul/tree/DatzAtWork-patch-non-root)

Comment: In fact, it would be best to build your own container inheriting from Consul, with the patch applied live thanks to sed. I've tried `RUN /bin/sed -i 's/^\(.*set -- su-exec consul:consul "$@"\)/    if [ "$(id -u)" = "0" ]; then\n    \1\n    fi/' /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` which work well !

Answer (score 1):

In case if someone looking for the solution.
You can also use Consul image from Bitnami. They provide non-root images of popular apps.

```
docker pull bitnami/consul:1.4.4
```

- https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-consul
- https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/consul/tags

Answer (score 0):

If /consul is an nfs mount, it might be that `root_squash` and `all_squash` are set at the server. That will result in chown operations to fail, because new files/folders will automatically be given to nobody/nogroup.

If you can change the share (temporarily) to use `no_root_squash` and `no_all_squash` until all files have been setup, you should be fine. As that filesystem typically is persisted, that should be only necessary once, so afterwards you can reset it to `root_squash` and `all_squash` again.

Answer (score 0):

```
user: consul
environment:
  - CONSUL_DISABLE_PERM_MGMT=yes
```